# Reordering start menu entry in start menu folder

Tags: install4j

I am evaluating install4J. I have a requirement to have some start menu entries.

sample menu (start menu folder)
 - Sample Product (menu entry 1)
 - Sample Product Uninstaller (menu entry 2)

However it is showing in reverse order.

sample menu (start menu folder)
 - Sample Product Uninstaller (menu entry 1)
 - Sample Product (menu entry 2)

How can I change it?

Answer (score 0):

The order is alphabetical unless changed by the user. For example, change the name to "Uninstall Sample Product" and the uninstaller will be last.

Unfortunately, there is no Windows API that would allow the installer to change this order programmatically.